# Gradle installDist without resource files

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Given the following project setup, running `./gradlew run` prints out `Hello World` correctly by reading in a resource file, but `./gradlew installDist && ./build/install/appresourcetest/bin/appresourcetest` does not, as it cannot find the resource file. Why is that, and how can I fix this issue while keep using the `installDist` task?

As the resource is inside the jar, this probably has something to do with `installDist`'s wrapper scripts' classpath setup, but that's where my understanding ends.

/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group 'com.example.application'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = "demo.Main"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

}
```

/settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'appresourcetest'
```

/src/main/resources/test.txt

```
Hello World
```

/src/main/java/demo/Main.java

```
package demo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //should not fail:
        String content = getFile("test.txt");
        System.out.println(content);
    }


    //code taken from:
    //https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/
    private static String getFile(String fileName) {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");

        //Get file from resources folder
        ClassLoader classLoader = Main.class.getClassLoader();
        File file = new File( classLoader.getResource( fileName).getFile());

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner( file)) {

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                result.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            scanner.close();

        } catch ( IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result.toString();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar/20389418#20389418), you should not try to read the `test.txt` as a `File`, but ask for an `InputStream` to the ClassLoader using `getResourceAsStream` method. You should rewrite your method `getFile`, to somethin like:

```
private static String getFile(String fileName) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
    try (InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName); Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in)) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            result.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception here
    }
    return result.toString();

}
```

And also change `String content = getFile("test.txt");` to `String content = getFile("/test.txt");`